# reader.readAsDataURL() not working on iOS or Android but in Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, filereader

I want to get a base64-String from an firebase hostet image-URL.
It's working well on all Browsers, but not when I'm building an iOS or Android App with ionic.

```
getDataUrl(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.responseType = 'blob';
      request.onload = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
          resolve(e.target.result)
        };
        reader.onerror= function (e) {
          console.log('Error:', e.target.error.code);
          reject(e.target.result)
        };
      };
      request.send();
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately it seems to stop at reader.readAsDataURL(request.response); but there is no logged error to check.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add this:

```
  if (request.response instanceof Blob) {
          const realFileReader = (reader as any)._realReader;
          if (realFileReader) {
            reader = realFileReader;
          }
        }
```

from
https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/issues/505#issuecomment-698831447